# Google FCM - can not subscribe to topic - returns 502 or "error INTERNAL"

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to subscribe device token to a topic on server. According to [FCM server docs](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server) proceeding the request:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AAAA...qC1GXg" \
  --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -X POST  -d '{}' \
 "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/BY7kK...rbZ/rel/topics/mytopic"
```

which returns :

```
502. The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds
```

The same 502 is returned when I'm trying to get token info with "details" parameter, like this:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AAAA...C1GXg" \
   "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/BY7kK...rbZ?details=true"
```

While if not adding "details" parameter, it all ok - it returns 200 and json data:

```
{"applicationVersion":"24","attestStatus":"UNKNOWN","application":"com.my.app","scope":"*","authorizedEntity":"...","appSigner":"...","platform":"ANDROID"}
```

I have also tried a batchAdd:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AAAA...81GXg" \
  --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -X POST \
  -d '{"to":"/topics/mytopic", "registration_tokens": ["BY7k...rbZ"]}' \
 "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd"
```

and it ends up with :

```
{"results":[{"error":"INTERNAL"}]}
```

Authorization key and device token I use should be OK, since I can get token data (without topics), and sending messages to that device (also using curl) works OK.
Still, this 502 is happening for more than 24h for me so far.

That's a new FCM project - I'm not migrating from GCM or anything. Android app is live on market for some time, but I haven't used cloud messaging there before.

Any ideas with what could be wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause. In case if someone will make the same mistake:

My Android app is published under one Google account, while I have created a project in Firebase console under a different account.
Having the app and Firebase project under same Google account - and all works like a charm.

Meanwhile, Google maps API keys, which also are used in my Android app, were generated under that second account, and everything is OK.

Comment: Hi, you should [mark as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/305652) your answer